# How to find entities not being ridden

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I tried this:

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,Passengers:[]]
```

It doesn't do anything. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Short answer is no, you're not doing it right.  The passengers information lives in the data tag, which the `kill` command doesn't have access to.  You'll have to tag the entities with the scoreboard before you kill them.

Comment: Isn't the kill command for killing players?

Comment: @Beminfire `/kill` was changed in 1.8 to support target selectors, and `@e` was also introduced in 1.8 to target non-player entities.

Comment: @Skylinerw Oh, I didn't know that. Probably since I stopped playing Minecraft in 1.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target selectors do not support looking for NBT data. You must mark the entity with a label first and then target the entity using that label:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=ArmorStand,tag=!NoRiders] add NoRiders {Passengers:[]}
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,tag=NoRiders]
```

Answer (score -1):

As of Minecraft 1.13, target selectors do support NBT data, meaning that your command, after correcting a few syntax errors and updating it to the new version, would work:

```
/kill @e[type=armor_stand,nbt={Passengers:[]}]
```